# JavaScript SDK: Login popup before clicking the login button

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

i'm new on Javscript SDK, still learning and trying to create a mobile web application and all what i'm trying to do is check for the user logged in status. If the user is not logged in or not authorize the app show the standard normal login button with no extra permissions. But when i test it, if i don't login and opens the web application page, before clicking the login button a login dialog automatically popups two/three times. After i cancel or close the dialog, when i click the Login button, nothing happens. I'm testing from desktop computer using mozilla user-agent trick. I will be very thankful if someone can review my code and guide me to the right direction. Thanks.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'app_id', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
    FB.getLoginStatus(fbLoginStatus);
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', fbLoginStatus);
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
<script>
function fbLoginStatus(response) {
     if (response && response.status === 'connected') {
        document.getElementById('loginButton').style.display = 'none';
        greetUser();
     } else {
        showLoginButton();
     }
  }
function authUser() {
   FB.login(fbLoginStatus);
}
function showLoginButton() {
  document.getElementById('logbutton').innerHTML = (
  '<input id="loginButton" type="button" value="Login!" onclick="'+authUser()+'" />'
  );
}
</script>
<div id="logbutton"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function showLoginButton() {
  document.getElementById('logbutton').innerHTML = (
  '<input … onclick="'+authUser()+'" />'
  );
}
```

You are actually *calling* the function `authUser` here (because that’s what `functioname()` does).

What you want instead is

```
'<input … onclick="authUser()" />'
```